# Codeigniter URL ReWriting Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am working a codeigniter project. for example I have a controller Blog and a method category with param.
When i go to a link 
`<a href="domain.com/blog/category/2">Developer Blog</a>`
it works fine. which redirect to a page `developer blog`. 
Is it possible to rewrite the url as `domain.com/blog/developer-blog` dynamically ? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically ? If you mean during the runtime, then you can change the href value of the link by javascript.

Comment: `https://domain.com/blog/developer-blog` points to `domain.com/blog/category/2` , `https://domain.com/blog/user-blog`  points to `domain.com/blog/category/3` something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `application/config/routes.php` and try following (if you want exact as mentioned in question)

```
$route['blog/developer-blog'] = 'blog/category/2';
$route['blog/user-blog'] = 'blog/category/3';
```

for dynamic routing you may use this

```
$route['blog/developer-blog/(:num)'] = 'blog/category/$1';
$route['blog/user-blog/(:num)'] = 'blog/category/$1';
```

so your URL now should be looks like `https://domain.com/blog/developer-blog/1`, `https://domain.com/blog/developer-blog/2`

or `https://domain.com/blog/user-blog/1`, `https://domain.com/blog/user-blog/2` etc

for more see http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html